# NetBeans and Maven: Removing local project dependency and force maven to use from repository

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have a problem with my maven project opened in Netbeans (7.3.1  and 7.4).

Let's say I have a maven project A which depends on maven project B based on dependency defined in pom.xml of A. Both projected are opened/loaded in my Netbeans.  When I build project A, it automatically refers to project B locally rather than downloading dependency from nexus.

How do I force maven to not to use local project as dependency?  Only reason I keep open project B is to refer the code.

To work around this issue, I have to unload project B, sometime delete it before I can build project A.

Comment: A temp solution is to change the directory of the project "A". Do not delete it.

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn clean install -U
```

-U means force update of dependencies.